# Numeric SKUs being rounded frontend

Tags: frontend, product-view, sku, additional-information

Odd one, we have an SKU that is 063.665.

Frontend however under additional information it shows as 63.67.

So it strips the leading 0 and rounds the end.

Does anyone know how I can stop this rounding under additional information?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found that Magento rounds if an attribute value is numeric, to fix this for `SKU` I did the following:

In `app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/YOURTHEME/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml`

Change

```
<?php
  $_MyValue = $_data['value'];
  if (is_numeric($_MyValue))
  {
    $_MyValue = round($_MyValue, 2); //round to 0.00
  }
?>
```

To:

```
<?php
  $_MyValue = $_data['value'];
  //IF ATTRIBUTE IS NOT SKU THEN GO AHEAD AND ROUND IT
  if($_data['label'] !== "SKU"){
    if (is_numeric($_MyValue))
    {
      $_MyValue = round($_MyValue, 2); //round to 0.00
    }
  }
?>
```

This will only round attributes that aren't `SKU`.